# Every number eventually equals 4

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, number-sequence

This is my first Puzzle posting on here. If I can figure out how to do a spoiler, I will add in a hint. Best of luck!

I heard this one a while back, and I don't know how well known it is.

Example 1:

> -75 = 19
>     19 = 8
>     8 = 5
>     5 = 4
>     4 = 4

Example 2:

> 252 = 18
>     18 = 8
>     8 = 5
>     5 = 4
>     4 = 4

Figure out the process of how I am go form any number and get it to be 4=4.

Prove that you have figured it out how I am doing it by getting 74 all the way down to 4=4

Comment: Three answers in a matter of seconds...

Comment: @AggieKidd I was surprised, I guess it more well known then I thought if was, or a lot easier then I thought it was

Comment: You've got an incredibly smart group of people here. They've seen a lot of things. I think I've seen this before.

Comment: It took me 20 mins just to solve the 3 of them with knowing how to do it. They must be gods!

Comment: Pretty much :) Some around have a reputation for speedy answers.

Comment: @Deusovi Yeah it's basically the exact same thing just different numbers.  I just could not remember the "cosmic" part so I left it out.

Comment: @Jaconah: We have a **lot** of puzzles here. If you don't make it up yourself, I can practically guarantee we have it somewhere on here.

Comment: @Deusovi I heard it a very long time ago and never since I figured it was something someone in my family came up with, but I guess it was not. Sorry

Comment: @Jaconah: No need to apologize! It happens all the time - it can be really hard to dig through the archives, even with the search function.

Comment: Completely understandable @Jaconah.  Thanks for posing a puzzle to us!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This puzzle is solved by

> Counting the letters in the English representation of each number. Every number eventually counts down to "four", which has four letters and becomes the terminus.

I feel like the explanation of the algorithm supersedes the meaningfulness of providing a solution from a specific example, but if I am required to do so for the sake of a green check, here it is:

> 74 = seventy-four : 11 letters
>  11 = eleven : 6 letters
>  6 = six : 3 letters
>  3 = three : 5 letters
>  5 = five : 4 letters
>  4 = four : 4 letters

Comment: That is how to figure it out but you did not prove you did by proving it by getting 74 all the way down to 4 :=)

Comment: That's better :=) I will be less picky if I ever come up with another one next time!

Answer (score 3):

> 74 = 11
>   11 = 6
>   6 = 3
>   3 = 5
>   5 = 4
>   4 = 4

Comment: Yep! You where correct I will mark you as the accepted answer when I can, I have to wait about 5 Minutes.  I guess this was a lot easier then I thought it was gonna be.

Comment: 1. Ian McDonald was 1 second faster than me.  2. I have seen similar puzzles before (and perhaps even on this site).

Comment: He just explained how to do it, he did not do "Prove that you have figured it out how I am doing it by getting 74 all the way down to 4=4"

Answer (score 3):

> Seventy four = 11
> eleven=6
> six=3
> three=5
> five=4
> four=4 :-)

Comment: Yep! You where correct to bad you where about 30 seconds slower then Gamow :P   I guess this was a lot easier then I thought it was gonna be.

Comment: Yeah, I typed the numbers out to make it easy to see how it was done. I should have been quicker on the draw.